# Leading Zeros in Excel showing up in cell but not in formula bar

Tags: excel, formatting, leading-zero

I downloaded some data from SAP into excel and the format is a custom one where the leading zeros are shown in the cell but do not appear in the formula bar.

When I try to format all of the cells to text, I lose all of the leading zeros. This is what the majority of help articles say to do, but I simply want to make the actual values of the numbers as they appear in the cell.

Is there a way I can make the values of the numbers the same as they appear in the cell? Could this involve some kind of special copying and pasting?

Comment: Use TEXT() formula with the second criterion of the format that is being used.

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate, I'm very new to this :) by the way, the format is nine digits ie '000000000', and all the numbers in the list having varying numbers of numners other than zero before the leading zeros

Answer (score 2):

Use a helper column and the formula `=TEXT(A1,"000000000")`. That will produce text values with leading zeros and nine digits.

Copy the formula down. Then copy the resulting cells and use Paste Special > Values to paste the results over the original data. After that you can delete the helper cells.

Comment: after searching for so long, finally got the way to solve my problem.